# Rundeck/WINRM - Rundeck manage to connect, move file, failing executing inline powershell script

Tags: python, powershell, rundeck, winrm

Currently I am facing a very confusing issue.

1. I am executing a job from (Rundeck) to (remote windows machine) using winrm as executor and file copier, which execute an inline powershell script.
2. Tried and worked fine on one of 3 environments.
3. On the Preprod, and Prod Rundeck.. Same job (exported/imported), fails, though same setting on the 3 environment, same script, same args, even same windows version.
4. I added a WINRM Check connection step, and it succeeds.

[image: WINRM Check step]

5. Rundeck manage to throw the script on the machine (with wrong name however), which means authentication is going well. However, it fails with this abstract error.

> [ERROR  ]  Execution finished with the following error (winrm-exec.py:304)[root]
> [ERROR  ]  The parameter is incorrect.  (extended fault data: {u'fault_subcode': 'w:InvalidParameter', u'fault_code': 's:Sender', u'wsmanfault_code': '87', 'transport_message': u'Bad HTTP response returned from server. Code 500', 'http_status_code': 500}) (winrm-exec.py:305)[root]
> [WinRMPython]: result code: 1, success: false
> Failed: NonZeroResultCode: [WinRMPython] Result code: 1

[image: Failure]

6. When I try to execute the thrown Powershell script locally from the machine it works well.

WinRM plugin version: 2.0.9

Python: 2.7.17

Comment: Is that happening with every Powershell script? You tested sending single commands (or a single PowerShell script) to a windows server and work OK? Which Windows version are you using? How is your winrm windows side configuration? (check this: https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/rundeck-winrm-plugin/wiki/Windows-Server-Setup) Could you share a script example to test? (please change any potentially sensitive information).

Comment: @MegaDrive68k 


Is that happening with every Powershell script?
- Yes.. It does fail even with single commands steps, with same exact error mentioned.

Windows versions ?
- Windows servers [2008/2012/2016]

- WINRM conf -- Well set from steps mentioned in URL of the plugin.

- Script ? It is not script related issue, as I mentioned, even single commands steps failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future references, the solution is [here](https://groups.google.com/g/rundeck-discuss/c/61xHAUo3ac8/m/Rxo148eWBQAJ). Switching to Python 3 interpreter (instead of Python 2) on Default Node Executor and Default File Copier (Project Settings > Edit Configuration > Default Node Executor and Default File copier tabs) solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Switching to python3 in WINRM resolved the problem. However, it caused problem for Windows server 2008 and older version.

So if you have both Windows OS version [pre and post 2008], you would need to split RUNDECK projects, and have winrm available on both python2 and python3.